# PHP include numeric

Tags: php, sql-injection

If I build my pages like this do I have to check if news_id is numeric in news.php too? Or is this safe?

**index.php:**

```
    if (ctype_digit($_GET['news_id'])) include('news.php');
```

**news.php:**

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id = $_GET[news_id]");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    if (!mysql_num_rows($query)) exit('The news you're trying to read do not exist.');
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are absolutely correct, you should never allow any user input directly into your database, or any other sensitive area.

You should validate/sanitize all input from $_GET, $_POST  etc... You can use PHP’s built in [filter functions](http://php.net/filter) or use those built into a framework such as Cake PHP or Symphony, which both make handling user data a lot easier.

jonstjohn has a good point you are leaving yourself open sql injection this way, and other forms of attack based around feeding malicious code into you application.

Worth reading Jeff Atwood’s [25 most dangerous programming mistakes](https://blog.codinghorror.com/top-25-most-dangerous-programming-mistakes/) for a bit of background on these issues, and others besides.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, you should.

Someone might (and will) request news.php, bypassing index.php.

Answer (score 0):

You really should escape your data and sanitize it before sending it into MySQL.  No guarantee someone won't try to send something malicious in through the post data.

```
$news_id = (int)$_GET[news_id];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id = " . 
                      mysql_real_escape_string($news_id));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

if (!mysql_num_rows($query)) exit('The news you're trying to read do not exist.');
```

Comment: -1. your code is redundant and it seems you just have no idea what does it actually do.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's **not** safe;
2. Don't check, convert it to integer using intval();
3. Never, ever put GPC variables in SQL without escaping or casting;

Comment: what do you mean convert it to integer? how do i do that?

Comment: $news_id = intval($_GET['news_id']);